Componentization in React-Native using redux toolkit to publish in npm
I'm currently working in some projects with React-Native and their design is similar to each other. Then comes the opportunity to make our custom components reusable.
We have custom component with a touchable that shows a modal with a list of items when clicked. I need to share states and dispatch actions from this touchable to modal and vice versa, so we are using redux toolkit for this. The problem is that when we dispatch an action to the modal, all of the others modal elsewhere where we use that custom component also receive this action.
We tried using ContextAPI to wrap it in a provider, but because of how it works, every state change made in the modal by a dispatch action from touchable results in both of them re-rendering, even if the touchable didn't depends of the state in the modal.
A simplification of our code now:
<Provider> // Here is the store logic from redux toolkit
  <CustomSelector>
    <CustomTouchable />
    <CustomModal />
    // Others custom components
  </CustomSelector>
</Provider>

Inside CustomTouchable
const CustomTouchable = (props: Props) => {
  const dispatch = useCustomSelectorDispatch()
  function onPress() {
    dispatch(changeModal())
  }

  return <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
    // boring stuff
  </TouchableOpacity>
}

Our CustomModal:
const CustomModal = () => {
  const illchange = useCustomSelector()
  return <Modal>
    // We use illchange here
  </Modal>
}

How should I rewrite this code to be possible to distribute in npm and make it easy to implement multiple of those in a project by only putting <CustomSelector /> wherever you want in your code without having to configure anything in redux of your project? And of course a CustomSelectorA cannot affect CustomSelectorB.

Which specific issue or problem would you like to narrow the focus of your post to? The working with a specific modal "instance", or NPM publishing? Please pick on or the other to ask about in this post, splitting the other into its own post, with complete details OFC. For the Redux issue you just need to uniquely identify the modal you want to interact with. Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve]? Can you share your Redux code for the store, the state slice that manages the modal state, and any selectors/etc, and the complete UI components working with them?

Invoke the modal with a prop that distinguishes its instances. So the components re-using it don't just render <CustomModal data={ ... } /> but instead something like <CustomModal data={ ... } slug="name_of_current_screen" />. Use a different string for slug for every instance of the modal. slug is just a suggestion, you might have a better name in mind. This is how some reusable modal components like https://facelessui.com/docs/modal/api#modal are built.
The redux stuff backing the modal needs to take these slugs/instances of modals into account and separate their state accordingly. Every slug could by a key in an object for example, the value could be an object holding the specific state of one modal instance.
Example:
modals: {
    screen1: {
        isOpen: true
    },
    screen2: {
        isOpen: false
    }
}

Regarding publishing on npm: Better post a separate question about that if you run into issues. Generally, relying on redux for state management of a reusable modal library is not a good idea. You'd have to rely on the consumer app's redux provider. Context API is the way to go here I think. You mentioned that trying this caused a problem with re-rendering. Is that actually a real problem, performance-wise or UX-wise? I imagine that most of the time only one of these modals is visible (since this is kind of how modals work).
